# How can I insert code blocks in draw.io UML

Tags: uml, draw.io

I am drawing UML with draw.io. And I want to insert a code block aside a class UML. When I write code(java/c) in a 'Text' block, it seems not tidy. Is it possible to insert a tidy code block (like markdown code block) in a UML page of draw.io?

Answer (score 4):

There is no native support for "tidy" code blocks in draw.io.

A workaround would be to create a picture of your code-block using a tool like [carbon](https://carbon.now.sh/) and import it into your UML diagram as an image.

Comment: I think, the "best" way would be to use an UML modeling tool, rather than a drawing tool.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. But I am studying code of a framework. So drawing UML makes ideas more clear for me.